# Select larger value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown with the lists of times.

My condition is-

`select only option whose value is just greater than current time`

However, I have implemented the way i could do it and this is working fine but there must be a better way of doing this, I am afraid that my implementation may break in some certain conditions.

Here is what I have done-

**HTML-**

```
   <select name="RunID" id="RunID" >
    <option>Select Departure Time...</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="12:30:00" >12:30</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
   var arrayTimes = [];

 $('#RunID option').not(':first-child').each(function () {

 var timeNow = new Date().toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");

 if (Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + $(this).val())
     > Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + timeNow)) {

         arrayTimes.push($(this));
        }
     });

if (arrayTimes.length > 0) {
     arrayTimes[0].attr('selected', 'selected');
   }
```

and the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m39eodde/1/)

**Edit-**

May be this question is creating confusion so I simply put an example for this.
As in my dropdown there are times `09:00:00`,`12:30:00`,`15:30:00`...

Now the current time is **12:58:25** seconds.

so accordingly the default selected value would be `15:30:00` because this is most nearly greater value than this current time.

Also, **I am not trying to disable any of values which doesn't match with the condition!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

JS:

```
var D = new Date();
var T = D.getTime();
var options = $('#RunID option[data-departuretime]');
var op = options.filter(function (el) {
    var d = new Date(D.getFullYear() + " " + (D.getMonth() + 1) + " " + D.getDate() + " " + $(options[el]).attr("data-departuretime"));
    return d.getTime() > T;
});
$(op[0]).attr("selected", "selected");
```

HTML:

```
<select name="RunID" id="RunID">
    <option>Select Departure Time...</option>
    <option data-departuretime="09:00:00">09:00</option>
    <option data-departuretime="13:35:10">13:35:10</option>
    <option data-departuretime="15:30:00">15:30</option>
    <option data-departuretime="18:30:00">18:30</option>
    <option data-departuretime="22:30:00">22:30</option>
    <option data-departuretime="01:30:00">01:30</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m39eodde/2/

Comment: The OP is trying to disable all options whose time has already passed on this day. So if it's 4 pm, all options prior to 4 pm should be disabled

Comment: OP mentioned that : "I am not trying to disable any of values which doesn't match with the condition" .

Comment: Yeah I think OP changed the wording around, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the options that are older as disabled so users won't be able to select them.

```
<option value="09:00:00" disabled>09:00</option>
```

And with jQuery as

```
$('#RunID option').prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: No this is not my question. I would have done that so simply! I am pointing out an alternate way of my procedure if any.